# ¿Cómo puedo insertar un dato de tipo date en una tupla desde SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Estoy programando una aplicacion para gestionar las tablas de una base de datos (insertar, borrar, actualizar, consultar...), usando como SGBD Oracle, y como ORM Sqlalchemy

Tengo que insertar una nueva tupla en una tabla de la Base de Datos, introduciendo los datos desde teclado, pero esa tabla tiene un campo tipo date que no se como introducir

La clase asociada a la tabla es esta:

```
class Alimento(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'alimento'
    codigo = Column(CHAR(5), primary_key = True)
    descripcion = Column(String(50))
    fechac aducidad = Column(Date)
    establecimiento = Column(CHAR(5), ForeignKey('establecimiento.codigo'))
    fecharecogida = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    codvoluntario = Column(CHAR(2), ForeignKey('voluntario.codigo'))
    entregado = Column(SmallInteger)
```

Y he intentado crear un nuevo objeto con esta linea, para poder introducirlo con el comando add

```
NuevoAlimento = clases.Alimento(codigo='ABCD0', establecimiento='A8377', fecharecogida = '01/07/2015', codvoluntario = 'T6')
```

Pero, cuando ejecuto add(NuevoAlimento), me salta este error:

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

¿Cómo puedo introducirlo para que Oracle me lo admita?

Comment: ¿Podrías aclarar a que te refieres con 'tupla', si a una tupla de Python o a un registro de la tabla de la base de datos?

Comment: Me refiero a un registro de la BBDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He podido solucionar el problema con el siguiente código:

```
NuevoAlimento = clases.Alimento(
                    codigo='ABCD0', 
                    establecimiento='QWER4', 
                    fecharecogida = datetime.strptime('10/11/2016', "%d/%m/%Y"),
                    fechacaducidad = datetime.strptime('09/05/2017', "%d/%m/%Y"), 
                    codvoluntario = 'I0',
                    entregado = 0
                )
```

Comment: @aldanux gracias por la edicion